# Deferreds in a piece of real code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, jquery-file-upload

I have some idea about Deferreds and what they do but I can't understand their usage in a piece of code I am working with right now. This code is from [jquery-file-upload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) and file [jquery-fileupload-ui.js](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-ui.js):

```
stop: function (e) {
    var that = $(this).data('blueimp-fileupload') ||
            $(this).data('fileupload'),
        deferred = that._addFinishedDeferreds();
    $.when.apply($, that._getFinishedDeferreds())
        .done(function () {
            that._trigger('stopped', e);
        });
    that._transition($(this).find('.fileupload-progress')).done(
        function () {
            $(this).find('.progress')
                .attr('aria-valuenow', '0')
                .children().first().css('width', '0%');
            $(this).find('.progress-extended').html('&nbsp;');
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    );
},

_addFinishedDeferreds: function (deferred) {
    if (!deferred) {
        deferred = $.Deferred();
    }
    this._finishedUploads.push(deferred);
    return deferred;
},

_getFinishedDeferreds: function () {
    return this._finishedUploads;
},
```

In the stop method, there are two constructs that I don't understand:

1)

```
$.when.apply($, that._getFinishedDeferreds())
.done(function () {
    that._trigger('stopped', e);
});
```

2)

```
deferred = that._addFinishedDeferreds();
//and later in the _transition function
deferred.resolve();
```

The second construct repeats throughout the whole code. I can see that _addFinishedDeferreds creates a deferred (if it is not passed as an argument), adds it to _finishedUploads and that deferred is later resolved. But I am missing the meaning of all this. What is it good for? Why the code can't work without it? And I don't understand the meaning of the first construct at all. Anyone can shed some light on this?

Comment: Deferreds can be really powerful, but what I like least about them is it's possible write some really, really obtuse code with them.  And someone should be admonished for using no comments to explain what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I assume you understand basic usage of `Deferreds`, including `resolve()` and `$.when()`.

From my understand of this code snippet, the `stop` function will be called multiple times, each time a new `Deferred` is created and will not be resolved until the transition is completed, though I don't know what transition it is because you did not show us its code. The `Deferred` object here, is to signal the completion of transition, and then a `stopped` event is triggered.

#### Details

1)

```
$.when.apply($, that._getFinishedDeferreds())
.done(function () {
    that._trigger('stopped', e);
});
```

`$.when.apply($, that._getFinishedDeferreds())` generates a new `Deferred` which is resolved after every `Deferred` is resolved in the array returned by `_getFinishedDeferreds()`. Then the callback function in `done()` triggers the `stopped` event.

2)

```
deferred = that._addFinishedDeferreds();
//and later in the _transition function
deferred.resolve();
```

Your understanding is correct. The intention of this code (if I guess correctly) is to make sure the event is not triggered until all transition is finished.

However if so there's a bug that the event trigger callback:

```
function () {
    that._trigger('stopped', e);
}
```

is attached each time `stop()` is called so the event may be triggered multiple times.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug that the stop event might be triggered multiple times. Rather it is an intention. Very nice explanation anyway. Thank you!